# Keyboard not working in FreeBSD installer on MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: usb, macbook-pro, freebsd, liveusb

I'm trying to install FreeBSD 11.1-RELEASE on my 2017 MacBook Pro (the touch bar one). It boots the bootloader screen fine, and the keyboard works perfectly there.
However, as soon as I select a boot option (single- or multi-user), my keyboard stops working, not responding to any keypresses.
Any help would be welcome!